# How to turn on vlc background play?

Tags: vlc, services, system-tray, background-process

I want to play song in background. But when I click cross button on window title-bar vlc stop. I already tried systray icon and run as daemon process. Not working. Maybe I am doing wrong. But is there any way to play vlc in background like a daemon like I before play in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/664826/1039759 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229790/341192 , https://askubuntu.com/q/176038/925128